# unable to connect to Genymotion server. please check your internet connection

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

When I am trying to open Genymotion, this dialogue appear:

[image: unable to connect to Genymotion server. please check your internet connection]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi! looks like my answer does the thing. Would you mark it as the best answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me the problem resolved after confirming my email address. Search your mail for a letter with activation link and then restart genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

So check your email, since you verified it opens Genymotion again and now if it is connected to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check you setup any proxy for genymotion and proxy is working.